# Proxmox - Assign more memory to KVM VM

Tags: kvm-virtualization, virtual-memory, proxmox

Is it possible to assign more memory to a KVM virtual machine without restarting it?
I changed the memory size of a VM using the Proxmox web interface, but can't see that increase in the guest.

Comment: do you mean memory hotplug?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the [HotPlug](http://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Hotplug_%28qemu_disk,nic,cpu,memory%29) feature of Proxmox. Please look through the URL carefully. There are nuances for both Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your guest you must have particular balloning driver in your system:

- Linux: check `CONFIG_VIRTIO_BALLON` kernel option
- Windows: follow instructions [how to add Balloning driver](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization_Host_Configuration_and_Guest_Installation_Guide/form-Virtualization_Host_Configuration_and_Guest_Installation_Guide-Para_virtualized_drivers-Mounting_the_image_with_virt_manager.html) and [how to start service](http://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Dynamic_Memory_Management)
- FreeBSD: [guest notes](http://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/FreeBSD_Guest_Notes#Enable_Virtio)